# Importing EarthVision ASCII to ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, ascii, xyz

How do I import a surface map from Petrel in EarthVision ASCII Format to ArcGIS?

I have a file from surface map in Petrel that I want to export to ArcGIS Desktop.

I used the tools 3D ASCII to Feature Class but its shows nothing, just blank.

The tool shows successful processing but when i check the TOC I did not have anything. just blank.

The file type has information about XYZ.

Here is the example of my ASCII file

[image]

no header in my file..
its just contains XYZ

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  Please **[edit]** your question to tell us *how* you were using the ASCII to FC tools, and what exactly you mean by it "always shows nothing".  It would also be useful to show a sample of your ASCII data

Answer (score 1):

You will need to edit your ASCII file to just have the XYZ fields in it.  The `ASCII 3D to Feature Class` tool isn't smart enough to recognise which columns of data are the XYZ, particularly if there is no header row.

I suggest you open the ASCII file in a text editor, delete the un-required columns and save the results out to a new ACSII file.  Then use that as input to the `ASCII 3D to Feature Class` tool.

[image]

Comment: Excel can do evil things to large files (where "large" isn't all that large -- 32K). It's almost better not to have it on the same computer where GIS processing occurs, just to prevent the pain and suffering.

Comment: Good point @Vince, reference to Excel has been removed from my answer.